# How to Run Batch Files Silently And Hide The Console Window?

Tags: node.js, electron

Actually i am using  nodejs + electronjs  for my application and also i am using screensaver for my app.When i start my batch file it executes and shows cmd prompt window on top of my screensaver.So,i want to execute my batch file in background.Can you please give perfect solution for my need?

Comment: how do you start your batch file from your app currently?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Save as **invisible.vbs**:

```
CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").Run """" & WScript.Arguments(0) & """", 0, False
```

Then run your script after calling the vbs script

```
invisible.vbs <script>
```

Comment: I don't want to write any vbs script. I want to run it only by the batch file itself.

Answer (score 0):

you can use either batch script

```
    @echo off //for remving console text

   //Other codes 

   exit /b 0  //for removing console


   pause>nul
```

I have also faced such type of situation where I had to generate PDF files and allow printer to execute print command for printing pdf files with default printer.for this purpose I have used sumatrapdfreader.I have also developed a package print I think it will be helpful for u.I am sharing link to u.
[package link on github](https://github.com/krdheeraj51/node-printer)